# Why $\frac{3n+1}{2^i} $ not of a form of 6m+3?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I am writting a paper here, and found amusing thing, which I yet can't explain myself.

Suppose $n,m,i\in \mathbb{Z}$

Lets take some arbitrary *n*.

Now lets $\frac{3n+1}{2^i}$, so that result is odd (*i* is maximally possible integer)

The result is odd, but cant be of a form $6m+3$

Why is it so? I mean - I understand why it is odd, I dont see why it is not of a $6m+3$ form. Any other odd integer does fit nicely.

Comment: Just a curiosity question : Are you dealing with the Collatz conjecture?

Comment: building on it, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is equivalent to taking the fraction mod 6, which you can do with CRT:

The fraction is always 1 mod 2 (odd number)

Also, $$\frac{3n+1}{2^i}=\frac{3n+1}{(-1)^i}=(-1)^i\mod 3$$

Which is only -1 or 1 obviously.

The results combined give 1 or 5 mod 6, none of which is 3 mod 6. (In addition, 3 mod 6 implies 0 mod 3)

To conclude, the fraction is not in the form of $6k+3$

Sorry for the bad formatting, I’m typing on phone haha.

Comment: haha. same here. Thanks, my number theory got bit rusty.

i will think at home, and most probably accept the answer.
thanks a lot!

Comment: yyep, man, thanks, this is explanation i neeed.

Answer (score 0):

this is true, because $3n+1$ is not divisible by $3$, but $6m+3$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: This thought occured to me, there was something I didnt like about this explanation.. will expand on it at home